# Maximum amount of characters

Tags: string, return, character, max, letters

can anybody help me with this given assignment? "Write
a
function
that
takes
as
input
the
message
(a
string)
and
checks whether
the
number
of
characters
is
less
than
160
or
not.
If
the
length
of
the
message
is
less
than
160,
the
message
should
be
returned.
If
the
length
of
the
message
is
greater
than
160,
a
string
consisting
of
only
the
first
160
characters
should be
returned."

I am unsure how to design a program that prints a string consisting of only 160 letters if the amount of letters are above.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Just check the string.length and if it was above 160 then, get the substring(0,160) that's it.

Comment: "Can you do my assignment for me" type questions where you have shown no attempt to try the question yourself are frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string contains more than 160 characters, loop from 1 to 160 (or 0 to 159 if your language is zero based), each time outputting the character at the position of the loop index. You can also use a substring function if your language has one.